# Getting multiple lines of input in C++

Tags: c++, input, while-loop

The first line contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100). Each of the following n lines contains one word. All the words consist of lowercase Latin letters and possess the lengths of from 1 to 100 characters.
(Source: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A)

How would you get input from the user given n?  I tried using a while loop but it doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int i;

    while (i<=n) {

        cin>>i ;
        i++;

    }



}
```

Comment: `cin>>i ; i++;` **Aawww!** That looks weird :-/ ...

Comment: how do you want to store that input?

Comment: if you want to just read it, this will work

    `#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int i=0;
        string xd;
        while (i<=n) {
            cin>>xd ;
            i++;
        }
    }`

It will read things one word at a time, and  store them in string 'xd'. You can chose to either append it to other things, put it into an array of string into [i] element, or anything else you want.

Comment: @random21 Code in comments is so **baaaad**! Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: because such simple program is not worthy of being considered an answer.

Comment: @random21 _'because such simple program is not worthy'_ No, that's a stupid POV. Code doesn't render very well in comments, beyond very short emphasized snippets. So please avoid this!

Comment: FYI, accessing an uninitialized variable results in [_undefined behavior_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is really quite far off of what you need.  What you wrote is extremely wrong such that I cannot provide advice other than to learn the basics of loops, variables, and input.  The assistance you need is beyond the scope of a simple question/answer, you should consider buying a book and working through it cover to cover.  Consider reading [Programming Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/)

Here is a working example of something approximating your question's requirements.  I leave file input and output as an exercise up to you.  I also make use of C++11's front and back std::string members.  You would have to access via array index in older versions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int totalWords;
    cin >> totalWords;
    stringstream finalOutput;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalWords; ++i){
        string word;
        cin >> word;
        if (word.length() > 10){
            finalOutput << word.front() << (word.length() - 2) << word.back();
        }else{
            finalOutput << word;
        }
        finalOutput << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "_____________" << endl << "Output:" << endl;
    cout << finalOutput.str() << endl;
}
```

With that said, let me give you some advice:

Name your variables meaningfully.  "int i" in a for loop like I have above is a common idiom, the "i" stands for index.  But typically you want to avoid using i for anything else.  Instead of n, call it totalWords or something similar.

Also, ensure all variables are initialized before accessing them.  When you first enter your while loop i has no defined value.  This means it could contain anything, and, indeed, your program could *do* anything as it is undefined behavior.

And as an aside: Why are you reading into an integer i in your example?  Why are you then incrementing it?  What is the purpose of that?  If you read in input from the user, they could type 0, then you increment by 1 setting it to 1... The next iteration maybe they'll type -1 and you'll increment it by 1 and set it to 0... Then they could type in 10001451 and you increment by 1 and set it to 10001452...  Do you see the problem with the logic here?

It seems like you are trying to use i as a counter for the total number of iterations.  If you are doing this, do not *also* read input into i from the user.  That completely undermines the purpose.  Use a separate variable as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to have something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int theInputNumbers[n];

    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
        cin >> theInputNumbers[i];
    } 
}
```